# Uninstalling Spyder installed by pythonXY

Tags: spyder

My spyder IDE got broken. Pressing F9 does not send code to the ipython console, the indentation is wrong, and more. I've tried `pip install spyder --upgrade` but that didn't fix the problems.

I'm looking to uninstalled and then re install spyder. I've looked at the documentations, but there is now clear why illustrating how to un-install it.

On my machine, spyder was installed together with pythonXY. Im thinking about uninstalling pythonXY and then installing a newer version of pythonXY, but that seems like an overkill for only fixing spyder.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try ```spyder --reset``` to reset the preferences ?

Comment: No, going to give it a try. thanks!